# Is entittyfieldquery result can be loaded into select list?

Tags: database

Trying to populate select list in VBO action form (basically could be anyform) and using enityfieldquery to get list. By this methods $result object contains node arrays.

Can this array can be loaded into select list directly? or we need to apply node_load_multiple on $results array.

Reason why I am asking is, there are many field and for the select list, only title and nid is enough right?

Are there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this array can be loaded into select list directly? or we need to apply node_load_multiple on $results array.

A FAPI select list expects an Array with `id` and `title`. An entityfieldquery returns only a list of IDs unless you get creative. Typically you perform extra work to `load` fields you want to show as text in your select field. You can do this via SQL, `node_load` a view resultset ... whatever means you're comfortable with.

EDIT

Well I didnt say you have to use node load. There are various extensions to EFQ that let you use community created EFQ classes:

- The most recent is https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mikeytown2/2209909
- A slightly older less pretty module is https://www.drupal.org/project/efq_extra_field

Comment: ok got it, only entityfieldquery is not enough :(. > extra work to load fields . thats what I am afraid of using node_load_multiple with lot of fields and it is not necessary for select list at all.

Comment: please see my edit.